# Leaflet with custom map (CRS) - how to convert JPG to TileLayer tiles

Tags: leaflet

I have a JPG file with a map which isn't in a real scale, and can't be represented by real geographical latitude and longitude, so I so the Leaflet CRS solution and this seems like the way to go.

The problem is that the map file (JPG) size is ~30MB and can't be loaded in a single request, so I read a bit more and found the TileLayer solution.
I even found a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davido/r2ms3dnp/) (the code is also provided below) :)

Now, my only problem is how can I take the JPG file and convert it to layers? Is there an online / offline tool for that?
As far as I understand, all I need is to split the large image to 256px x 256px tiles, place it in directories in my server and TileLayer will do the rest?

```js
var w = 14000;
var h = 10000;
var mapMinZoom = 2;
var mapMaxZoom = 5;      
var _map = L.map('map', {
        maxZoom: mapMaxZoom,
        minZoom: mapMinZoom,
        crs: L.CRS.Simple,
        zoomControl: false,
        attributionControl: false,
        detectRetina: true
      });

var _mapBounds = new L.LatLngBounds(
    _map.unproject([0, h], mapMaxZoom),
    _map.unproject([w, 0], mapMaxZoom));
_map.setMaxBounds(_mapBounds);

var _mapCenter = _map.unproject([w/2, h/2], mapMaxZoom);
_map.setView(_mapCenter, 3);

var _tileLayer = L.tileLayer(
        'http://d3uxxcqax6u8f1.cloudfront.net/assets/img/map/{z}/map_{x}_{y}.png', {
        minZoom: mapMinZoom, maxZoom: mapMaxZoom,
        bounds: _mapBounds,
        continuousWorld: true,
        noWrap:true,
        tileSize:250,
        crs: L.CRS.Simple,
        detectRetina:false
      }).addTo(_map);
```

```css
html, body, #map { width:100%; height:100%; margin:0; padding:0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/0.7.7/leaflet.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/0.7.7/leaflet.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

See e.g. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/221671/how-to-split-a-tif-image-into-several-tiles and http://www.gdal.org/gdal2tiles.html

Once you have the tiles, yeah, just place them next to your files and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

I found this program for creating local stored tiles:
http://libvips.github.io/libvips/API/current/Making-image-pyramids.md.html

Command:

```
vips.exe dzsave input.jpg tiles_folder --layout google --background 0 --centre --suffix .jpg[Q=100]
```

where
input.jpg - your big image
tiles_folder - output folder
--layout google - this is important for leaflet
--background 0 - black background
--suffix .jpg[Q=100] - tiles quality (100%)

And then in leaflet:

```
L.tileLayer('tiles_folder/{z}/{y}/{x}.jpg', {  
tileSize: 256 // or 512  
crs: L.CRS.Simple // this is important for nongeo maps
}).addTo(map);
```

Comment: I follow this instruction and I already read the documentation. but found an error
`no matches found: .jpg[Q=100]`

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
import numpy as np
import cv2
import math

def image_tailing(img_array: np, tile_size=256, min_zoom=0, max_zoom=3, method='centered/left-up'):
    h = tile_size
    w = tile_size
    img_height, img_width = img_array.shape[:2]
    max_side = max(img_height, img_width)
    
    for z_lvl in range(min_zoom, max_zoom + 1):
        if not os.path.isdir(f"crop/{z_lvl}"):
            os.mkdir(f"crop/{z_lvl}")
        # Required size of largest side in current zoom level 
        required_side_max_zoom_lvl = tile_size * 2 ** z_lvl
        rs_max = required_side_max_zoom_lvl
        scale_percent = rs_max / max_side * 100
        width = int(img_array.shape[1] * scale_percent / 100)
        height = int(img_array.shape[0] * scale_percent / 100)
        print(f"zoom={z_lvl} w={width}, h={height}")
        dim = (width, height)
    
        # resize image
        img_resized = cv2.resize(img_array, dim, interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
    
        # Find the proportional coefficient and round up it to integer
        # and our sides of picture will be proportional by tile size
        alpha_width = math.ceil(width / tile_size) * tile_size
        alpha_height = math.ceil(height / tile_size) * tile_size
        # filled square with alpha channel
        filled_square = np.zeros((alpha_height, alpha_width, 4), np.uint8)
        # Getting the centering position
        if method == 'centered':
            ax, ay = (alpha_width - img_resized.shape[1]) // 2, (alpha_height - img_resized.shape[0]) // 2
        else:
            ax, ay = 0, 0
        # Pasting the 'image' in a centering position or left-up position
        filled_square[ay:img_resized.shape[0] + ay, ax:ax + img_resized.shape[1]] = img_resized
        x, y = 0, 0
        k, l = 0, 0
        while y < alpha_height:
            while x < alpha_width:
                if not os.path.isdir(f"crop/{z_lvl}/{k}"):
                    os.mkdir(f"crop/{z_lvl}/{k}")
                crop = filled_square[y:y + h, x:x + w].copy()
                cv2.imwrite(f'crop/{z_lvl}/{k}/{l}.png', crop)
                k += 1
                x += w
            k = 0
            l += 1
    
            x = 0
            y += h
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    max_zoom = 5
    img = cv2.imread('img/1.png', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
    image_tailing(img, min_zoom=0, max_zoom=max_zoom, method='left-up')
    print("End of script")
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).